# Using an Anonymous method to populate a property in an object initializer

Tags: c#, lambda

Assuming `sr` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, I want to use code like this to do an inline calculation using two of the items from `sr.Lines()`.  The problem is that the lambda is of type  "lambda expression" and not a Decimal, which shares is expecting.  Is there any way to do this type of inline method in an object initializer?

```
var trades =
 from line in sr.Lines()
 let items = line.Split('|')
 select new Trade
       {
         Total = () => { 
           return Convert.ToDecimal(items[1]) + Convert.ToDecimal(items[2]);
         },
         Name = items[3]
       }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a decimal expression, not a function:

```
var trades =
 from line in sr.Lines()
 let items = line.Split('|')
 select new Trade
       {
         Total = Convert.ToDecimal(items[1]) + Convert.ToDecimal(items[2]),
         Name = items[3]
       };
```

Comment: I should have been more specific, I just used that as a small, readable example of what I wanted to do.  The reality is that I might have relatively complex logic to calculate each of those fields with if or case statements, etc.

Comment: Then just wrap your complex logic in separate methods and call them in the initialization. Or if it's too long, don't use object initialization syntax at all.

Comment: So your answer is, no, there is no way to do this?  I have to use the object initializer syntax since it's part of a linq query.  I'm aware that I could wrap it in a function, but I was trying to figure out if there was some sort of inline anonymous method way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else ends up here looking for a solution like I did.

Check [How to call anonymous function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923864/how-to-call-anonymous-function-in-c).

```
var trades =
from line in sr.Lines()
let items = line.Split('|')
select new Trade
   {
     Total = ((Func<decimal>)(() =>
     {
         return Convert.ToDecimal(items[1]) + Convert.ToDecimal(items[2]);
     }))(),
     Name = items[3]
   };
```