# How to call anonymous function in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-function

I am interested if it's possible using C# to write a code analogous to this Javascript one:

```
var v = (function()
{
    return "some value";
})()
```

The most I could achieve is:

```
Func<string> vf = () =>
{
    return "some value";
};

var v = vf();
```

But I wanted something like this:

```
// Gives error CS0149: Method name expected
var v = (() =>
{
    return "some value";
})();
```

Are there some way to call the function leaving it anonymous?

Comment: Can you say what you want to do with the code exactly? What's the desired input and output?

Comment: @Ahmad: The question is completely clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Why go through all the rigamarole of defining an anonymous function and invoking it when you could simply place the body of the anonymous function *right there* and it would be invoked when the code runs?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I use it this way inside <%= %> ASP.NET construction.

Comment: @Alexander: Interesting. So what you are doing is essentially using a bunch of *statements* in a context where an *expression* is required. Isn't there some way you can run statements without having to jump through these hoops?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I could use <% %> tags and Response.Write() at the end, but I would prefer the method discussed above by aesthetic reasons. :)

Comment: See [why-cant-c-sharp-use-inline-anonymous-lambdas-or-delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687942/why-cant-c-sharp-use-inline-anonymous-lambdas-or-delegates)

Comment: @EricLippert I've used this technique to implement a "poor mans `let`" for C#. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591939/268581) for details.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, but C# is statically-typed, so you need to specify a delegate type.

For example, using the constructor syntax:

```
var v = new Func<string>(() =>
{
    return "some value";
})();

// shorter version
var v = new Func<string>(() => "some value")();
```

... or the cast syntax, which can get messy with too many parentheses :)

```
var v = ((Func<string>) (() =>
{
    return "some value";
}))();

// shorter version
var v = ((Func<string>)(() => "some value"))();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should guess myself.

Comment: I guess then it isn't possible with anonymous types or in Linq expressions? (Consider `() => new { "test" }` - can you call it literally?)

Comment: @NetMage No, but you can declare a generic method that takes the lambda and simply returns it (`static Func<T> Lambda<T>(Func<T> func) => func`) and then call it (`Lambda(() => new { Foo = "Test" })()`). Unfortunately you need a separate overload for every unique number of lambda parameters.

Comment: This lets me invoke non-trivial code that I would only ever need to call once, and store it in a variable: `int width = new Func<int>(() => { stmt; stmt; stmt; return something; }).Invoke();`

Comment: @Timwi, See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591939/268581) for something similar. A function called `Let`.

Answer (score 1):

## `Let`

With this helper function:

```
T Let<T>(Func<T> f) => f();
```

your example is then:

```
var v = Let(() => { return "abc"; });
```

## Why the name `Let`?

It can be used similarly to `let` in other languages like Haskell, Scheme, and other Lisps.

This in Scheme:

```lisp
(define c 
  (let ((a 10)
        (b 20))
    (+ a b)))
```

and this in Haskell:

```hs
c = 
  let 
    a = 10
    b = 20
  in a + b
```

can be written using `Let` in C#:

```cs
var c = Let(() => 
{
    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;

    return a + b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could then utilize such a construct to enclose context - closure-

```
Control.Click += new Func<string, EventHandler>((x) =>
new System.EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}))(valueForX);
```

Comment: This is doing way more than you need to.

Comment: Wasteful, redundant invocation of a function that doesn’t need to be a function. It sounds like you are coming from a JS background; this is necessary in JS only because variables are scoped to an entire function in JS. C# has proper correct scoping, so this is not necessary.