# C# 4.0 Anonymous Functions

Tags: c#-4.0, anonymous-function

How do I do the following shown in Javascript in C# 4.0:

```
var output = doSomething(variable, function() {
    // Anonymous function code
});
```

I'm sure I've seen this somewhere before but I cannot find any examples.

Comment: you can use delegates or Lambda expressions

Comment: See [how-to-call-anonymous-function-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923864/how-to-call-anonymous-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look in to [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) though it's not QUITE like JavaScript because C# works quite a bit differently. You may also want to check out [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Example Code:

```
namespace Test {
    class Tests {
        delegate string MyDelegate();

        public void Main(string[] args) {
            var output = doSomething("test1", () => { return "test2";} );
        }

        public string doSomething(string test, MyDelegate d) {
            return test + d();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example which does the same as outlined in the question?

Comment: @GateKiller: I added an example.

Comment: I guess not as simple as JS but that's the best example I've seen on how to do the above. Thank you :)

Comment: @GateKiller: Yeah, it's C#'s strongly typed nature. It's not really meant to do stuff like that. Lambda Expressions make it a lot better but still that's probably about as simple as you're gonna get.

Answer (score 5):

Using a lambda expression (parameterless, therefore empty parentheses), it is very simple:

```
var output = doSomething(variable, () => {
    // Anonymous function code
});
```

In C# 2.0, the syntax was a bit longer:

```
SomeType output = doSomething(variable, delegate {
    // Anonymous function code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var output = (x) => {
     // Anonymous function code
 };
```

Comment: So does (x) equal doSomething() in my example?

Comment: `x` is the parameter of the anonymous function.

Comment: I've quickly tested something like `(MessageBox.Show) => { return "Hello World"; }` but it throws an error. Could you please provide a full example so that I understand fully?

Comment: I'm getting the impression that I need to declare the delegate before I can use it. Is this correct? If so, doesn't that defeat the point of them?

Comment: what exactly are you trying do? differently from Java Script you need to tell what type x is when "it is difficult or impossible for the compiler to infer the input types"